# Clicking User Accounts in the System Settings breaks everything

Tags: unity-control-center

Clicking on other settings like Displays or Keyboards works fine, the new window opens and I can change the settings.
But when I click on User Accounts, it does not open, and I am unable to click on anything else, and the window will not close and stays on top. I can't use anything else until I force log out.
This is 14.04.4 LTS and Unity

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you upgrade graphical stack and do not install `libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xxxx`, where `xxxx` is your graphical stack name.

Check which version is installed by

```
dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core
```

and see which line is with `ii` chars

```
ii  xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily                            2:1.17.2-1ubuntu9.1~trusty1                         amd64        Xorg X server - core server
```

If it is `wily`, then run

```
sudo apt-get install libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily
```

and the issue will be fixed.